# Rails rake db:migrate option to not overwrite existing tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rake

Is there a `rake db:migrate` option to prevent rake from overwriting existing tables if they have the same schema? I will also accept an option that prevents overwriting existing tables regardless of the schema. I would have thought not overwriting would be the default and would require a `--force` flag to do so.

Comment: I am pretty sure Rails only generates a `CREATE TABLE` statement and the database raises an error when the table already exists. Can you please elaborate and post one example in which a Rails migration would overwrite existing tables?

Answer (score 2):

In migration, you can check if table or column exists before executing the code:

```
unless table_exists?(:test)
  # do something
end

unless column_exists?(:test)
  # do something
end
```